# ¿Error en LOAD DATA INFILE en Python3.4?

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente script en python3.4 para insertar datos a una tabla MySQL:

```
    import pymysql

    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='',db='bd',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    try:
        query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/data.csv' INTO TABLE bd.down_data
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ESCAPED BY '"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
        (campo1, campo2, campo3);"
        cursor.execute(query)
        print('LOAD OK')
    except:
        print('query failed')

    result = cursor.fetchone()

    connection.close()
```

y me marca el siguiente error:

```
query failed
Traceback <most recent call last>:
File "test.py", line 14, in<module>
  result=cursor.fetchone()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 282, in fetchone self._check_executed()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py" line 78, in _check_executed
    raise err.ProgrammingError<"execute() first">
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: execute() first
```

Si ejecuto el SQL directamente en MySQL funciona sin problemas, alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal?

**********UPDATE***********

Agregue la sentencia `local_infile=True` a la conexión

```
import pymysql

    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='',db='bd',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,local_infile=True)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    try:
        query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/data.csv' INTO TABLE bd.down_data
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ESCAPED BY '\"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' (campo1, campo2, campo3);"
        cursor.execute(query)
        print('LOAD OK')

    except TypeError as e:
        print('query failed: '+e)

    result = cursor.fetchone()

    connection.close()
```

ahora ya veo que intenta hacer el `load` pero me da el sig warning:

```
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:329: Warning: <1262, ´Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns´>
self._do_get_result()
```

Este warning también me lo da workbench al ejecutar el load data infile directo pero me inserta los datos, entonces me imagino que la advertencia es porque en mi tabla `MySQL` tengo 3 columnas y en el `.csv` tengo mas de 3 columnas, entonces me imagino que `python` no lo soporta

Comment: Hola, si te fijas el `try` falla, en estos casos te recomiendo siempre  eliminar el `try-except` temporalmente o imprime la excepción en el `except` para ver que está pasando. La cadena de la query si la tienes tal y como está aquí para empezar tiene errores de sintaxis a causa de `'"'`, usa comillas triples `"""LOAD DATA....."""` o escapa el carácter.

Comment: @FJSevilla al parecer me hacia falta local_infile=True, ya actualice la pregunta y también me hacia falta escapar  `' " '`